# Output of code containing complex pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I was at an interview in which they asked me:

> What will happen if you compile the following code? Will it compile successfully? If yes, what will be the output?

```
static int a[ ] = {0,1,2,3,4};
int *p[ ] = {a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};
int **ptr = p;
ptr++;
printf(“\n %d %d %d”, ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr);
*ptr++;
printf(“\n %d %d %d”, ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr);
*++ptr;
printf(“\n %d %d %d”, ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr);
++*ptr;
printf(“\n %d %d %d”, ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr);
```

I has no answer. This was way more complex than the problems that I had solved.

Then they responded:

> The output will be:

```
111
222
333
344
```

After going home also I could not actually understand how it worked. Could someone explain this to me? Any help Appreciated.

Comment: You may also but yourself some interview points by explaining it will compile, but with a bunch of *format warnings* for attempting to print pointer differences as normal integers.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Statements outside a function in C? No way this compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets denote the addresses of array `a` with some arbitrary address numbers for better understanding (without taking the size of int into consideration).

`a[] = {0,1,2,3,4}`

`address value
1000   =   0 
1001   =   1
1002   =   2
1003   =   3
1004   =   4`

Now `int *p[ ] = {a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};` is a array of pointers. So its basically keeping some address. lets assume some arbitrary address for this array too

`address value
2000   =   1000 (a means address of a[0] and a+1 means address of a[1] and so on)
2001   =   1001
2002   =   1002
2003   =   1003
2004   =   1004`

`int **ptr = p;` is a pointer to another pointer. so its basically pointing to first address of array `p` which is `2000` and has a value of `1000`.

`ptr++;` advances the pointer `ptr` by one step. So its now pointing to the 2nd address of `p` which is `2001` with a value of `1001`.

Now `printf(“\n %d %d %d”, ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr);`:

value of `ptr` is `2001` and value of `p` is `2000` (because `p` means address of `p[0]`). So the difference is `2001-2000 = 1`

value of `*ptr` is `1001` and value of `a` is `1000`. So the difference is `1001-1000 = 1`

value of `**ptr` is 1. because `ptr=2001`. `*ptr = 1001` and `**ptr = 1` (value at address `1001`)